# Managing application settings with Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

Does anyone know what is the best way to manage application settings in azure container apps.

Azure functions has a configuration section to view and manage application settings, but no such option exist with azure container apps.

We can still use environment variables or Azure app configuration but is there any other way which is recommended for azure container apps?

Tried using environment variables

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you are configuring, among other things, you can use

- environment variables
- appSettings
- Key Vault
- database
- etc.